# Создание больших файлов через WinAPI.

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder

Здравствуйте. Работаю в C++ Builder 6. Вопрос в следующем.

Нужно сохранять строки в файл. Строк много. Порядка 300-800 мб. Сохранение можно сделать через потоки с сохранением в файл. Но хотелось бы избежать использования большого количества оперативной памяти.

Нашёл информацию, что так можно можно делать через трансляцию файла в памяти с помощью [WinAPI](http://eax.me/winapi-file-mapping/).

Но все примеры, которые я смог найти, работали только с уже созданными файлами. И самостоятельные попытки работать таким образом с файлом ни к чему, не привели. Может быть у кого нибудь есть такого рода пример?

Comment: dwMaximumSizeHigh и dwMaximumSizeLow пробовали в CreateFileMapping прописывать?

Comment: А с чего вы решили, что "сохранение через потоки в файл" займет много памяти - по крайней мере больше, чем при записи в отображенный на память файл?...

Comment: У Вас есть код, который ест много памяти при сохранении? Тогда покажите его. Если кода нет еще, то в чем тогда проблема?